# HTML list - Apply addClass() Only to First-Level LI Element (not Inner one)

Tags: jquery

I have the following code,

```
$('.main-menu li:nth-child(3)').addClass("active");
```

Which works, however, the HTML looks like this...

```
<ul>
    <li>menu item</li> 
    <li>menu item</li>
    <li>menu item       <!-- Target only this one! -->
        <ul>
            <li>menu item2</li>
            <li>menu item2</li>
            <li>menu item2</li> <!-- not this one -->
        </ul>
   </li>   
</ul>
```

And it adds the "active" class to both lists of `LI`s, any way to make it only add it once? Thank you

Comment: Your HTML is invalid; it'll work once you fix that.

Comment: Your selector is wrong. Adding an `ID` to `ul` and then `$('ul#your_id>li:nth-child(3)').` will solve it.

Comment: @Interrobang: where's the invalid html?

Comment: @Interrobang There's nothing wrong with the HTML. The third list item simply contains another list, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: @DavidThomas looks like it was fixed via edit directly after the post (is there a grace period where an edit log entry isn't shown?)

Comment: There is, it's five minutes (when last I checked). I had considered the chance of an edit, but when I looked I thought I saw invalid html, but then I realised it was just because of the lack of indentation. I wasn't sure if there was something I was missing, though, since that lack played tricks with my eyes.

Comment: @DavidThomas Your eyes are fine, there was a missing `</ul>` you can see in my LIVE demo, I used the exact OP's original code and had to add the missing *"closing"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Use the "immediate" *child* selector `>`

```
$('.main-menu > li:nth-child(3)').addClass("active");
```

http://jsbin.com/urekah/1/edit