# Adding class to parent child grandchild list items using javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add class to nested list items dynamically, even if the count of child and grandchild items change.

**A sample nested items would look like this:**

- **parent:** list1

  - **child:** list11

    - **grandchild:** list111
    - **grandchild:** list1112
  - **child:** list12

    - **grandchild:** list121
    - **grandchild:** list122

The issue is, if I add class using `ul li ul`, it applies to all child and grandchild items. Is there any way to add class separately to child, grandchild, great grandchild, and so on?

```js
$('ul li ul a').addClass('child')
```

```css
ul li a {
  color:red
}

.child {
  color:green;
}

a {
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Parent1
  <ul> 
    <li><a href="#">Grandparent</a>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Child</a> 
            <div>
              <ul>
                <li> <a href="#">Child1</a> 
                  <ul><li><a href="#"> Grandchild11</a></li></ul>
                </li>
                
                <li> <a href="#">Child2</a>
                  <ul><li><a href="#">GrandChild21</a></li><li><a href="#">grandchild22</a></li></ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div> 
          </li>
          
          <li>
            <a href="#"> Child2 </a>
            <ul><li><a href="#">GrandChild21</a></li><li><a href="#">grandchild22</a></li></ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div> <!-- Parent1 -->

<div>Parent2
  <ul> 
    <li>
      <a href="#">Grandparent</a>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Child</a> 
            <div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Child1</a> 
                  <ul><li><a href="#"> Grandchild11</a></li></ul>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Child2</a>
                  <ul><li><a href="#">GrandChild21</a></li><li><a href="#">grandchild22</a></li></ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div> 
          </li>
          
          <li>
            <a href="#"> Child2 </a>
            <ul><li><a href="#">GrandChild21</a></li><li><a href="#">grandchild22</a></li></ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div> <!-- Parent2 -->
```

Comment: Play around with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: Really didn't get which needs to be the final result ... can you clarify

Comment: @DaniP, I am trying add CSS classes to parent, child, grandchild,great grandchildren and till the hierarchy ends in the format of list1 > list11> list111 > list1111 ...(example)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML list - Apply addClass() Only to First-Level LI Element (not Inner one)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054435/html-list-apply-addclass-only-to-first-level-li-element-not-inner-one)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I updated the code to work with the structure given in your codepen.

All information regarding jQuery traversal can be found by looking through the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) or reading through the [w3Schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing.asp).

The following code recursively searches for `<li></li>` tags and their first `<a></a>` tags, giving each of them a class based on their position in the tree.

I also added `id` attributes to your "Parent1" and "Parent2" divs to initiate the loop.

**Sidenote:** Make sure your HTML is valid, as the code you posted in your codepen link had severe formatting issues and many, many closing tags were missing from key elements which would warp the list's structure.

See the below snippet, as well as [this updated codepen](http://codepen.io/BFG/pen/wJqwRp).

```js
$(function() {

  CreateListHierarchy($('#Parent1'), 'list');
  //CreateListHierarchy($('#Parent2'), 'list'); //Add this to sort both lists
  
});

function CreateListHierarchy(parent, className) {
 
 let firstList = $(parent).find('li:first');
 
  $(firstList).find('a:first').each(function() {
  
      $(this).addClass(className + '1');
      console.log($(this).text() + ', ' + $(this).attr('class'));
      CreateListHierarchy(firstList, className + '1');
  
  });
    
  $(firstList).siblings('li').each(function(sinblingIdx) {
  
   let currentSibling = this;
    
    $(currentSibling).find('a:first').each(function(index) { 
     $(this).addClass(className + (index + 2));
      console.log($(this).text() + ', ' + $(this).attr('class'));
      CreateListHierarchy(currentSibling, className + (index + 2));
    });
  
  });

}
```

```css
.list1 {
  color: red;
}

.list11 {
  color: green;
}

.list1121, .list1122 {
  color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Parent1">Parent1
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Grandparent</a>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Child</a>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Child1</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#"> Grandchild11</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Child2</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">GrandChild21</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">grandchild22</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"> Child2 </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">GrandChild21</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">grandchild22</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
  
<div id="Parent2">Parent2
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Grandparent</a>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Child</a>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Child1</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#"> Grandchild11</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Child2</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">GrandChild21</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">grandchild22</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @BFG , this is close to what I am looking, but the classes are being appled incorrectly , I tried giving css - https://codepen.io/divyar34/pen/oZwaZN

Comment: @divyareddy Your codepen has quite a few errors in the HTML. For instance, you missed quite a few closing tags for the <div></div> and <li></li> elements.. keep that in mind as it will cause issues in your javascript. I took the code from your codepen link and fixed the HTML as well as writing new JS code to apply the classes correctly. See my updated answer and codepen link above.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the CSS Selector for immediate child ( `>` ), in order to specify which level of element you are targeting. You may change your jQuery to something like this:

```js
// $('ul li ul a').addClass('child')

var parent = 'ul > li';
var child = ' > div > ul > li';

// to target the child
$(parent + child + ' > a').addClass('child');
// to target the grandchild
$(parent + child + child + ' > a').addClass('grandchild');
// to target the great grandchild
$(parent + child + child + child + ' > a').addClass('greatgrandchild');
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration:none;
}
ul li a {
  color:red
}
.child {
  color:green;
}
.grandchild {
  color:orange;
}
.greatgrandchild {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Grandparent 1
  <ul> 
    <li>
      <a href="#">Parent</a>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Child 1</a> 
            <div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Grandchild 1-1</a>
                  <div>
                    <ul><li><a href="#">Great Grandchild 1-1-1</a></li></ul>
                  </div>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Grandchild 1-2</a>
                  <div>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Great Grandchild 1-2-1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Great Grandchild 1-2-2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div> 
          </li>
          
          <li>
            <a href="#">Child 2</a>
            <div>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Grandchild 2-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Grandchild 2-2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div> <!-- Grandparent 1 -->

<div>Grandparent 2
  <ul> 
    <li>
      <a href="#">Parent</a>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Child 1</a> 
            <div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Grandchild 1-1</a> 
                  <div>
                    <ul><li><a href="#"> Great Grandchild 1-1-1</a></li></ul>
                  </div>
                </li>
                
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Grandchild 1-2</a>
                  <div>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Great Grandchild 1-2-1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Great Grandchild 1-2-2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div> 
          </li>
          
          <li>
            <a href="#"> Child 2</a>
            <div>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Grandchild 2-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Grandchild 2-2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div> <!-- Parent2 -->
```

> **IMPORTANT**
>   The above code will work as long as your nested elements have a uniform "pattern". If in any case they don't have, you can simply modify the value for `var child`, or add another one with a different value. For example:

```
var parent = 'ul > li';
var child = ' > div > ul > li'; /*ul enclosed in div*/
var grandchild = ' > ul > li'; /*ul not enclosed in div*/

// to target the grandchild
$(parent + child + grandchild + ' > a').addClass('grandchild');
```

## Here's a working demo in JSFiddle, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Give Id to your parent div

```
<div id="parent">
.
.
</div>
```

and use the following code

```
$('#parent ul li ul a').addClass('child');
```

so the class will append only to child and grandchild inside 'parent' id