# CSS3 - Display div h3 elements horizontally on hover with absolute position

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display `h3` elements of parent `div` on hover horizontally, 
as shown in screenshot below:

[image]

If I try `position: absolute`, all the `h3` elements are collapsing, which results in another issue: I am not able to hover and get the list of `h3`, as they are collapsed.

codepen url :https://codepen.io/divyar34/pen/PpjrYO

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">aaa</a>
        <div>
            <div>
                <h3>111</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>zz1</li>
                    <li>zz2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>1112</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>zz11</li>
                    <li>zz21</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>1113</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>zz1</li>
                    <li>zz2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">bb</a>
        <div>
            <div>
                <h3>2220</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>yy</li>
                    <li>yyyy</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>2221</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>yy1</li>
                    <li>yyyy1</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">cc</a>
        <div>
            <div>
                <h3>3330</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>ccccc</li>
                    <li>dddd</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>3331</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>ccccc</li>
                    <li>dddd</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>3332</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>ccccc</li>
                    <li>dddd</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>3333</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>ccccc</li>
                    <li>dddd</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
a{
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color:white;
    background:rgb(0,176,240);
    border:none;
}
ul li{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline;
    cursor:pointer;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 6px;
}
ul li:hover a{
    background:orange;
}
ul li:hover ul{
    width: 100%;
    visibility: visible;
}
ul li ul{
    display:block;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-top:5px;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 40px;
}
div ul{
    width:100%
}
ul li div{
    visibility: hidden;
    position:absolute;
}
ul li div div ul{
    display:none;
}
ul li:hover div{
    visibility: visible;
}
ul li div div{
    display:block;
}
ul li ul li div div h3{
    display:inline;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color:white;
    background:rgb(0,176,240);
    border:none;
}
```

Comment: check https://jsfiddle.net/0t9amg4q/ and explain a bit better what your expected result is, thanks

Comment: @Vickel, even in fiddle , I see that all h3 of div elements are collapsed after hovering on either divs - aaa,bb,cc

Comment: I can only guess, but change this css style: ul li div{
  visibility: hidden;
  position:relative;

}

Comment: @Vickel, it displays the elements vertically not in horizontally as shown in screenshot

Comment: I posted an answer below, with demo. Check if it helps you solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MAJOR EDITS: to accommodate the OP's added info on the issue**

First of all, you are using a lot of nested `div` and `ul`, so you should consider using classes to avoid unnecessary confusion. Alternatively, If using classes affects some functionalities, then make use of **[CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**, instead.

## Run the working snippet below, or

## Use this JSFiddle if you want to play around, further.

```css
/* New plus Modified CSS */
/*General CSS*/
li{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline;
    cursor:pointer;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    padding-left: 6px;
}
li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color:white;
    background:rgb(0,176,240);
    border:none;
}
li a + div div,
h3 + ul li {
    border: solid 1px grey;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 2px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
li a + div,
h3 + ul {
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-top:5px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 40px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
/*END General CSS*/

/*Hover CSS*/
li:hover a{
    background:orange;
}
li:hover a + div,
li a + div div:hover h3 + ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
/*END Hover CSS*/
/* END New plus Modified CSS */
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">aaa</a>
        <div>
            <div>
                <h3>111</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>zz1</li>
                    <li>zz2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>1112</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>zz11</li>
                    <li>zz21</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>1113</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>zz1</li>
                    <li>zz2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">bb</a>
        <div>
            <div>
                <h3>2220</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>yy</li>
                    <li>yyyy</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>2221</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>yy1</li>
                    <li>yyyy1</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">cc</a>
        <div>
            <div>
                <h3>3330</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>ccccc</li>
                    <li>dddd</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>3331</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>ccccc</li>
                    <li>dddd</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>3332</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>ccccc</li>
                    <li>dddd</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h3>3333</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>ccccc</li>
                    <li>dddd</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @ITWitch, displays as expected, is there anyway we can generalize the CSS without classes - submenu-1-box, submenu-1 menu-item

Comment: Would you mind telling me why you don't want to use classes?

Comment: If you don't want to use classes, it's up to you, but like I mentioned above, you'll be confused when it comes to hiding and showing your submenus on hover, and it will be difficult to debug them. If your 1st level `ul li` doesn't have a class and you set CSS rule for their hover, that CSS rule will also apply to the `ul li` inside them, whether you like it or not.

Comment: Thanks @ITWitch , I have updated the CSS to avoid classes from your approach.. https://codepen.io/divyar34/pen/dvRBJz

Comment: reason for avoiding classes is that to add classes, again I have use jquery and I am facing issue in adding classes to specific list and its child elements - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769342/adding-class-to-parent-child-grandchild-list-items-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: I see now. If that's the case, the CSS Selectors will be helpful for you https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp. I've also edited the JSFiddle to remove the classes: https://jsfiddle.net/flamedenise/4q6hmgtm/

Comment: if possible, could you please check my other question ? thank you

Comment: Glad I could help. Best of luck to you ;)